# Flux / Alt not updating props from store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, alt, immutable.js

I'm trying to rerender my React component with new props received from a store, but the props do not seem to get updated. This approach normally works for me, only in this case it does not.

**Component**

```
class Cart extends React.Component {

    static getStores() {
        return [CartStore];
    }

    static getPropsFromStores() {
        return CartStore.getState();
    }

    componentDidMount() { // tried componentWillMount also
        CartActions.updateCart();
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.cart); // empty object

        return (
            <div className="cart">
                {this.props.cart.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item.get('name')}</div>)}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default connectToStores(Cart);
```

**Actions**

```
class CartActions {

    updateCart() {
        this.dispatch();
    }

}

export default alt.createActions(CartActions);
```

**Store**

```
class CartStore {

    constructor() {
        this.bindActions(CartActions);

        this.cart = Immutable.fromJS([]);
    }

    updateCart() {
        this.cart = Immutable.fromJS(JSON.parse(localStore.getItem('cart')));
        console.debug('cart', this.cart); // returns the correct object
    }

}

export default alt.createStore(CartStore, 'CartStore');
```

The store receives the action event and retrieves the correct object from localStorage. However, the props of the component do not update, as they normally would.

Any help appreciated! Thank you :)

**Versions**

- React 0.14.3
- alt.js 0.17.9

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to your store somewhere in your view, usually componentDidMount, also if you are rending something from a store and it will change, it should either comes from a higher order component or simply becomes a state. In this case a state variable suits better.

So, something like this would work

```
componentDidMount () {
  CartStore.listen(this.onChange)
  CartActions.updateCart()
}

onChange () {
  this.setState({
    xxx: xxxx
  }) // or change props like yours if you insist 
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="cart">
            {this.state.cart.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item.get('name')}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The Flux implementation alt.js is doing that for me. The connectToStores method takes care of that. As I said, it works if I, for instance query an API. But with localStore it somehow does not.

Comment: This method does work, however it prevents true isomorphic rendering, different hashes are generated on server & client.

Comment: This question is old, but I have the same issue right now, I'm using the connectToStores, I can see that the store receives the action, but the view doesn't update the state.